# having only one bloc provider is better or having multiple bloc provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

I have a a bottom sheet, having group of radios and text input each of them have a separate class. Which way is better?

**Firstly:**

Radio Group have a bloc-provider and the text input have a group provider.

**Secondly:**

only both of them have the same bloc provider.